# Problem with :visited on class. Why does a:visited work fine, and .myarticle:visited not?

Tags: html, css, visited

```css
<!-- Style of myarticle-->
.myarticle{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px 5px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: bisque;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: graY;
}

a:link{
    color: silver;
}
 <!--The thing, I don't understand. .myarticle:visited does nothing, ??-->
a:visited, .myarticle:visited{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: black;
}
.myarticle:hover{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px 5px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #67B9B3;
    background-color: #224341;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

  
.myarticle:active{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px 5px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #67B9B3;
    background-color: #224341;
}
 <!-- main -->
.mymain{
    width: 70%;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: sienna;
    border: 2px solid peru;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 <!-- Footer -->
.headfoot{
    width: 70%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid peru;
    background-color: sandybrown;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
       
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Green.css">
        <title>Cyan</title>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <header class="headfoot">Kopfzeile</header>
            <main class="mymain">
                   <!--Hyperlink reference (a)-->
                    <a href="index.html">
                     <!-- first article -->
                    <article class="myarticle article01">
                            <h1>Artikel (1)</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
                    <a href="index.html">
                    <!-- second article -->
                    <article class="myarticle article02 unten">
                        <h1>Artikel (2)</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
                    </article></a>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IumYMCllMs" >
                      <!-- third article -->
                    <article class="myarticle article03">
                        <h1>Artikel (3)</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
                    </article><a/>
            </main>
        <footer class="headfoot">
        Fußzeile
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

[i don't know, why it's not working. Could someone explain me where's my fault?
Why is .myarticle:visited not working fine?:(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWeKE.png)

[I'm trying to change the style of myarticle if the link of a is visited.
But I'm a little bit frustrated actually. I don't know wheres my fault at.
what are the rules for ':visited' is it caused of the wrong usage? How do i write it then?]

Comment: You need to share your code if you want help

Comment: Don't include links to code... include the actual code in the question itself. The link will be invalid at some point, then this question will help no one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `.myarticle` cannot be "visited", I would go with:

```
a:visited, a:visited > .myarticle{
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: black;
}
```

Instead of:

```
<!--The thing, I don't understand. .myarticle:visited does nothing, ??-->
a:visited, .myarticle:visited{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: black;
}
```

`:visited` status applies to the links, you cannot apply this to the `article` items